# How can I transfer scam ERC1155 NFT's out of my Bifrost wallet?

Tags: transactions

I am having trouble getting rid of all the spam nft's that keep appearing in my wallet. I used to be able to send them to a trash address but these newer ones are not letting me. It is saying"failed to prepare transaction, ERC1155: Insufficient balance for transfer".
I have ETH and MATIC for possible gas fees but it doesn't even attempt to send it anywhere.
Any ideas on how to get rid of these spam/scam nft's that state I won thousands of dollars?

Answer (score 1):

Do not, most of these are actually looking for you to do just that so they can steal assets through a fake `transfer()` function. If you don't touch them, they can't have any effect on your wallet. Anyone that ever shared their address publicly has those tbf